# Drupal - Block visibility

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

I am using the below code in the block visibilty settings,  to only show the block if the user is a member, and not the admin.

What can I add to further filter it down to type of Organic Group Node.

i.o.w Only display if the currnt group being viewed = Organic Group Node Type X

```
<?php
  $in_og = FALSE;
if (module_exists('og')){
  $in_og = FALSE;
  $group_node = og_get_group_context();
  $gid02 = $group_node->nid;
  $gid = (int)$gid02;
  if ($gid02 == null) $gid = 0; 
  if (og_is_group_member($group_node)) $in_og = TRUE;
  if (og_is_group_admin($group_node)) $in_og = FALSE;
  if ($gid == 0) $in_og = FALSE;
}
return $in_og;
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like"

```
<?php
    $in_og = FALSE;
    $right_group = FALSE;
    if (module_exists('og')) {
        // get OG $group_node
        $group_node = og_get_group_context();
        if ($group_node->type == 'type-x') {
            // we have the correct group type
            $right_group = TRUE;
        }
        $gid = $group_node->nid;
        if (og_is_group_member($group_node)) {
            // show to members
            $in_og = TRUE;
        }
        if (og_is_group_admin($group_node)) {
            // hide from admins
            $in_og = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return $in_og && $right_group;
?>
```